# Create virtual queue for every session C#

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I want to process  requests in async but in sequence. I want to create a virtual queue for every session means all requests of one user process in a single queue but requests of another user in another queue. That is requests of both users process parallelly but, requests of the one user should be processed in sequnce.

How Can I implement this?  Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make a List of Queues ... List<TUser, Queue<TProcess>> ....

Comment: Do you want true async... or just one way? Are the users on the network with you or on the internet?

Comment: @TomRedfern - I want to process request in async. Users on internet.

Comment: Are you planning to support non-wcf consumers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the users are connecting directly to your service and not through a proxy you should define your service the following:

```
[ServiceBehavior(
    ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Single,
    InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession,    
  )]
```

`InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession` - This means that each client "gets" his own worker thread for his service instance for the entire session so multiple clients have multiple threads.
`ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Single` - Means that a client can only make one call at a time to the service so calls are processed in sequence.

Comment: Would have answered the same here. But one additional note: Setting the [ServiceContractAttribute.SessionMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.sessionmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property to `Required` should also be helpful in this situation.

Comment: Also note, this will only work if you are using wsHttpBinding, which limits you to connections from WCF consumers only. If you plan to support non-wcf, or even non-windows consumers, then you will not be able to use this approach. This is because per-session instancing relies on WS-ReliableMessaging and WS-Security SOAP extensions, both of which tend to be non-interoperable.

Comment: Additionally, it is almost *never* OK to use a singleton service instance, especially if you're expecting calls in high volumes over the internet.